# The specified cast from a materialized “System.Int32” type to the “System.String” type is not valid

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

Esto me pasa solo en producción, no en ambientes locales

> cannot set the 'Type' property (which is int) to a 'string' value
>
> The specified cast from a materialized "System.Int32" type to the
>   "System.String" type is not valid.

Aqui va parte del error

> [InvalidOperationException: The specified cast from a materialized
>   'System.Int32' type to the 'System.String' type is not valid.]
>       System.Data.Entity.Core.CommonInternal.Materialization.ErrorHandlingValuereader
>   1.GetValue(DbDatareader reader, Int32 ordinal) +253
>       lambda_method(Closure , Shaper) +164
>       System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materalization.Coordinator 1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper) +197
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()
>   +90
>       System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator 1.MoveNext() +108
>       System.Linq.WhereEnumerableIterator 1.MoveNext() +87
>       Def.CRM.Ventas.Presentacion.Controller.LoginController.SeleccionEmpresa(String
>   idCliente, String idUsuario, String idSesion, Int16 cantHoras) +94

Generalmente tenemos que reiniciar el IIS para que vuelva a funcionar

Funcion:

```
Function SeleccionEmpresa(ByVal idCliente As String, ByVal idUsuario As String, ByVal idSesion As String, Optional ByVal cantHoras As Int16 = 0) As ActionResult

        Dim empresaMgr As New EmpresaMgr()
        Dim empresas As IEnumerable(Of empresa) = empresaMgr.GetAllEmpresasCRM(idCliente)
        Dim options As String = "<option value='0'>Seleccione su Empresa</option>"
        For Each current As empresa In empresas
            options += "<option value='" + current.IDEmpresa.ToUpper() + "'>" + current.Nombre + "</option>"
        Next

        Return View(New With {.idCliente = idCliente, .idUsuario = idUsuario, .idSesion = idSesion, .combo = options, .cantHoras = cantHoras})
    End Function
```

Class:

```
Public Class EmpresaMgr
Private db As ERPEntities
Private idEmpresa As String

Private usaContextoExterno As Boolean = False

Public Sub New()
    Me.db = New ERPEntities(AppConfiguracion.getConnectionString("ERPData", "Defontana"))
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal idEmpresa As String)
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(idEmpresa) Then Throw New ArgumentException("idEmpresa")

    Me.db = New ERPEntities(AppConfiguracion.getConnectionString("ERPData", "Defontana"))
    Me.idEmpresa = idEmpresa
End Sub
Public Sub New(ByVal idEmpresa As String, ByRef context As ERPEntities)
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(idEmpresa) Then Throw New ArgumentException("idEmpresa")
    If context Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("context")

    usaContextoExterno = True

    Me.db = context
    Me.idEmpresa = idEmpresa
End Sub
Public Function GetByKey() As empresa
    Try
        Dim empresa = (From c In db.empresas Where c.IDEmpresa.Equals(idEmpresa, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault()
        Return empresa
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function

Public Function GetAll(ByVal idCliente As String) As IEnumerable(Of empresa)
    Dim listaEmpresas As IEnumerable(Of empresa)
    listaEmpresas = (From c In db.empresas Where c.IDCliente.Equals(idCliente, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    Return listaEmpresas.AsEnumerable()
End Function

Public Function GetAllEmpresasCRM(ByVal idCliente As String) As IEnumerable(Of empresa)
    Dim listaEmpresas As IEnumerable(Of empresa)
    listaEmpresas = GetAll(idCliente).Where(Function(f) f.IntCRM IsNot Nothing AndAlso f.IntCRM.Equals("S", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    Return listaEmpresas.AsEnumerable()
End Function
Public Function GetLogo() As byte()
    Dim empresa = GetByKey()
    If ((Not IsNothing(empresa)) AndAlso (Not IsNothing(empresa.ArcAdj))) Then
        return empresa.ArcAdj
    Else
        Return Nothing
    End If
End Function
Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    MyBase.Finalize()

    If Not usaContextoExterno Then
        db.Dispose()
        db = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

El error lo que indica es que en tu base de datos tienes una columna que es `INTEGER` pero en el modelo es `String` por lo que la materialización de `Int32` a `String` no puede ser posible.

Por ejemplo puedes que tengas la siguiente tabla:

```
TABLE PERSONA(
  id INTEGER,
  nombre VARCHAR(50)
)
```

Pero tu modelo sea el siguiente:

```
public class Persona
{
  public string Id { get; set;}
  public string Nombre { get; set}
}
```

En el ejemplo id en la tabla es `INTEGER` pero en el modelo `String` por lo que la conversión no puede efectuarse.

Identifica la columna esa columna y actualiza tu modelo para que refleje fielmente la estructura de base de datos.

<sub>Nota: disculpa que el ejemplo esta en C#. No conozco VB</sub>

Comment: Gracias por darte el tiempo para responder, lamentablemente he revisado la BD y el entity  model lo esta sacando de ahi mismo, no hay diferencias en cuanto al tipo de datos, existirá alguna especie de guia en el error que me permita saber donde realmente se está generando el problema?

Comment: @JaimeOlivares Puedes indicar cual es el metodo que esta lanzado el error o por lo menos publica el modelo? Asi quizas podamos tener una idea mas general. Y en cuanto a guia, si buscas encontraras la misma respuesta que acabo de darte.